# Get the Duration of an audio file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm a beginner in programming. What I'm trying to create is a bar to show the duration of the audio file that is playing in android studio, and if the user want to go forward or backward in the audio that is playing to be able by using that bar. And what kind of layouts do I have to use in xml?

Here is my java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_predici);
    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonpredica1);
    Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonpredica2);

    //button1
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player=MediaPlayer.create(prediciActivity.this,R.raw.cuisusinmijloculfurtunii);
            player.seekTo(length);
            player.start();


        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            length=player.getCurrentPosition();
            player.pause();

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's player.getDuration()

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `SeekBar` and set a listener in your `Activity` to listen to changes to the `SeekBar`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html